# This utility is primary meant to be used when PyInstaller is not installed

Tags: pyinstaller

I have python3.4 installed on a Windows7 machine.
I just installed PyInstaller on that machine using pip.
Then executed "pyinstaller.py test.py" from C:\Python34 folder in console which
(i) is not showing any error in console
(ii) is opening a text file which ends with 
    "# This utility is primary meant to be used when PyInstaller is not
     # installed, eg. when be run by a git checkout.
     from PyInstaller.**main** import run
     run()
    "
(iii) is not creating any test.exe anywhere.

How to execute PyInstaller to create a executable ?